# WiX 3.8 CAQuietExec and command string

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix-extension

I'm trying to do a custom action when unistalling an Application. These should be done in quiet mode. Therefore I've that part of code to make it working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="APPFOLDER">
            <RegistrySearch Id="PATH"
                    Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Type="raw"
                    Name="InstallPath" />
        </Property>
        <CustomAction Id="CleanupAppDirCmd"
                      Property="CleanupAppDir"
                      Value='rmdir /s/q "[APPFOLDER]"'
                      Execute="immediate"/>
        <CustomAction Id="CleanupAppDir"
                      BinaryKey="WixCA"
                      DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
                      Execute="deferred"
                      Return="ignore"
                      Impersonate="no"/>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="CleanupAppDirCmd"
                    After="CostFinalize"/>
            <Custom Action="CleanupAppDir"
                    After="RemoveFiles">
                REMOVE="ALL"
            </Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But nothing happens. The directory still exists after finishing the uninstall. The uninstall-log tells me following:

`MSI (s) (F8:20) [16:57:15:778]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CleanupAppDir,,)
MSI (s) (F8:20) [16:57:15:779]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=CleanupAppDir,ActionType=3137,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData=rmdir /s/q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\")
MSI (s) (F8:20) [16:57:15:780]: Creating MSIHANDLE (111) of type 790536 for thread 6176
MSI (s) (F8:C0) [16:57:15:780]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6D67.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
MSI (s) (F8:5C) [16:57:15:780]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (F8:5C) [16:57:15:782]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 6872 (0x1AD8).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [16:57:15:809]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [16:57:15:810]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:819]: Creating MSIHANDLE (112) of type 790531 for thread 2892
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:820]: Closing MSIHANDLE (112) of type 790531 for thread 2892
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:820]: Creating MSIHANDLE (113) of type 790531 for thread 2892
CAQuietExec:  Command string must begin with quoted application name.
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:820]: Closing MSIHANDLE (113) of type 790531 for thread 2892
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:820]: Creating MSIHANDLE (114) of type 790531 for thread 2892
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070057: invalid command line property value
MSI (s) (F8!4C) [16:57:15:820]: Closing MSIHANDLE (114) of type 790531 for thread 2892
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070057: failed to get Command Line`

I've tried several changes in the value of `CleanupAppDirCmd` but nothing worked. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmdir isn't an EXE that can be executed, it's a shell command internal to cmd.exe.

I'd suggest looking at [RemoveFolderEx Element (Util Extension)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html).  It'll be a much better solution including rollback of the delete if the install fails or is cancelled. (Very important)

Comment: Yes, using shell commands like that from MSI is an anti-pattern unless properly embedded in a coded custom action with appropriate error and exception handling - and even then I wouldn't use it if there was an alternative. Definitely use the Util extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The positioning of `RemoveFolderEx` Element was a bit tricky (as child of a `component`) but it solved my problem completely.